# Has anyone experience not being able to connect put with Pi after enabling the uncomplicated firewall?

Tags: networking

It seems after I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ufw
$ sudo su
$ ufw default deny incoming
$ ufw default allow outgoing
$ ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22 comment 'allow SSH from local LAN'
$ ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 50002 comment 'allow Electrum from local LAN'
$ ufw allow 9735  comment 'allow Lightning'
$ ufw allow 8333  comment 'allow Bitcoin mainnet'
$ ufw allow 18333 comment 'allow Bitcoin testnet'
$ ufw enable
$ systemctl enable ufw
$ ufw status
$ exit
```

I run into a issue with not being able to login into my Pi through putty after I close a session.

Is there something that happens to the connection between my router and the Pi that cuts the connection off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you are connecting to 192.168.1.73. Looks, like your local network is 192.168.**1**.0/24, and you opened connections to port 22 from 192.168.**0**.0/24.

`ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22 comment 'allow SSH from local LAN'`

So you may change settings of your local router to create local network 192.168.0.0/24 and then you'll be able to ssh into your Pi.

And looks like this question is more appropriate for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) than for bitcoin.se. There you could get better advice.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration `ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22` opens your Pi to incoming transactions to port 22 from IP addresses 192.168.**0**.*

Your whole home network seems to be configured to use IP addresses in the range 192.168.**1**.*, so you need to change the configuration command to

`ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22 comment 'allow SSH from local LAN'`

As you are not able to connect with SSH at the moment, the easiest way is probably to connect a keyboard and screen to the Pi and login locally.

Comment: But my router IP ia 192.168.1.254

Comment: Yes, that is the point.  It is *not* 192.168.0.254.